# Shortcut for Requiring Several 'sub-namespaces' with :as

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Consider this at the beginning of a Clojure program:

```
(ns my.core
   (:require [lib.a :as my1]
             [lib.b :as my2]
             [lib.c :as my3]
             [lib.d :as my4]))
```

is there a shortcut for this?

something like:

```
(ns my.core
   (:require [lib [[a :as my1]
                   [b :as my2]
                   [c :as my3]
                   [d :as my4]]]))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, it's called a [prefix list](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/require):

```
(ns my.core
  (:require (lib [a :as my1]
                 [b :as my2]
                 [c :as my3]
                 [d :as my4])))
```

Comment: Right—I believe there is no intention to add prefix list support to ClojureScript.